# Running go gives me - go clang: error: no input files

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, go, kubernetes, amazon-iam

```
go get -u -v github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/cmd/aws-iam-authenticator
```

on Mac OS X `10.13.6 (17G65)`

gives me:

```
go
clang: error: no input files
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Run `go get -u -v github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/cmd/aws-iam-authenticator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand specified repo does not exist or unaccessible, (your link returns 404) hence you are getting "no input files", it is pretty self explanatory.